# Modify a NER entity based on a pattern via regexner

Tags: regex, stanford-nlp

I am using regexner module to create some custom "TITLE" but what happened is that all the so called "PERSON" are recognized as "ORGANIZATION", when followed by those custom titles.

eg:

> sentence_text,tokens,lemmas,ner_tags "Chairman of the Board Bienaime Jean-Jacques Files To Sell $4.6M of BMRN on 10/13/16.,"{Chairman,of,the,Board,Bienaime,Jean-Jacques,Files,To,Sell,$,4.6,M,of,BMRN,on,10/13/16,.}","{Chairman,of,the,Board,Bienaime,Jean-Jacques,Files,to,sell,$,4.6,m,of,bmrn,on,10/13/16,.}","{TITLE,TITLE,TITLE,TITLE,O,O,O,O,O,MONEY,MONEY,MONEY,O,STOCK,O,DATE,O}"
>   "Chmn Bienaime Jean-Jacques of BioMarin Pharmaceutical Inc (BMRN) filed a Form 144 on 10/13/2016 with the S.E.C reporting the following changes in ownership: Transaction Date  Transaction Type                      Share Amount   Price per Share     Value ----------------  ------------------------------------  -------------  ---------------  ------------   10/13/2016        Intent to Sell *                            53,125         $86.98        $4.6M * - Pursuant to Rule 10b5-1 automatic trading plan.","{Chmn,Bienaime,Jean-Jacques,of,BioMarin,Pharmaceutical,Inc,-LRB-,BMRN,-RRB-,filed,a,Form,144,on,10/13/2016,with,the,S.E.C,reporting,the,following,changes,in,ownership,:,Transaction,Date,Transaction,Type,Share,Amount,Price,per,Share,Value,----------------,------------------------------------,-------------,---------------,------------,10/13/2016,Intent,to,Sell,*,""53,125"",$,86.98,$,4.6,M,*,-,Pursuant,to,Rule,10b5-1,automatic,trading,plan,.}","{Chmn,Bienaime,Jean-Jacques,of,BioMarin,Pharmaceutical,Inc,-lrb-,BMRN,-rrb-,file,a,form,144,on,10/13/2016,with,the,s.e.c,report,the,follow,change,in,ownership,:,Transaction,Date,Transaction,type,share,Amount,Price,per,share,value,----------------,------------------------------------,-------------,---------------,------------,10/13/2016,intent,to,sell,*,""53,125"",$,86.98,$,4.6,m,*,-,pursuant,to,rule,10b5-1,automatic,trading,plan,.}","{TITLE,PERSON,PERSON,O,ORGANIZATION,ORGANIZATION,ORGANIZATION,O,STOCK,O,O,O,O,NUMBER,O,DATE,O,O,MISC,O,O,O,O,O,O,O,O,O,O,O,O,O,O,O,O,O,NUMBER,NUMBER,NUMBER,NUMBER,NUMBER,DATE,O,O,O,O,NUMBER,MONEY,MONEY,MONEY,MONEY,MONEY,O,O,O,O,O,O,O,O,O,O}"
>   Chairman of the Board Gallagher Thomas C Buys $267.7K of GPC on 10/20/16.,"{Chairman,of,the,Board,Gallagher,Thomas,C,Buys,$,267.7,K,of,GPC,on,10/20/16,.}","{Chairman,of,the,Board,Gallagher,Thomas,C,buy,$,267.7,k,of,gpc,on,10/20/16,.}","{TITLE,TITLE,TITLE,TITLE,ORGANIZATION,ORGANIZATION,ORGANIZATION,O,MONEY,MONEY,MONEY,O,ORGANIZATION,O,DATE,O}"
>   {Chief,Executive,Officer,Chen,Zhou,Files,to,sell,$,1.0,m,of,yy,on,9/29/16,.}","{TITLE,TITLE,TITLE,O,O,O,O,O,MONEY,MONEY,MONEY,O,STOCK,O,DATE,O}"
>   "CEO Chen Zhou of YY Inc (YY) filed a Form 144 on 9/29/2016 with the S.E.C reporting the following changes in ownership: Transaction Date  Transaction Type                      Share Amount   Price per Share     Value ----------------  ------------------------------------  -------------  ---------------  ------------   9/29/2016         Intent to Sell                              18,550         $52.63        $1.0M The Form 144 is filed with the Securities and Exchange Commision to reflect the information of any holder of restricted stock to sell those shares.","{CEO,Chen,Zhou,of,YY,Inc,-LRB-,YY,-RRB-,filed,a,Form,144,on,9/29/2016,with,the,S.E.C,reporting,the,following,changes,in,ownership,:,Transaction,Date,Transaction,Type,Share,Amount,Price,per,Share,Value,----------------,------------------------------------,-------------,---------------,------------,9/29/2016,Intent,to,Sell,""18,550"",$,52.63,$,1.0,M,The,Form,144,is,filed,with,the,Securities,and,Exchange,Commision,to,reflect,the,information,of,any,holder,of,restricted,stock,to,sell,those,shares,.}","{CEO,Chen,Zhou,of,YY,Inc,-lrb-,YY,-rrb-,file,a,form,144,on,9/29/2016,with,the,s.e.c,report,the,follow,change,in,ownership,:,Transaction,Date,Transaction,type,share,Amount,Price,per,share,value,----------------,------------------------------------,-------------,---------------,------------,9/29/2016,intent,to,sell,""18,550"",$,52.63,$,1.0,m,the,form,144,be,file,with,the,Securities,and,Exchange,Commision,to,reflect,the,information,of,any,holder,of,restricted,stock,to,sell,those,share,.}","{TITLE,PERSON,PERSON,O,STOCK,ORGANIZATION,O,STOCK,O,O,O,O,NUMBER,O,DATE,O,O,MISC,O,O,O,O,O,O,O,O,O,O,O,O,O,O,O,O,O,NUMBER,NUMBER,NUMBER,NUMBER,NUMBER,DATE,O,O,O,NUMBER,MONEY,MONEY,MONEY,MONEY,MONEY,O,O,NUMBER,O,O,O,O,ORGANIZATION,ORGANIZATION,ORGANIZATION,ORGANIZATION,O,O,O,O,O,O,O,O,O,O,O,O,O,O,O}"

Initially i thought of defining those names as PERSON inside my regexner.mapping file, however there are several instances of this and a possibility to scaleup. 
**How to define a regular expression over tokens, so if a TITLE is followed by ORGANIZATION then replace the ORGANIZATION to a PERSON**

eg:  /Match TITLE ORG/ -> { replace to} -> / TITLE PERSON/

Comment: @stanfordnlphelp any advice please

Answer (score 1):

I am having trouble recreating your issue.

I made a sample job title rule file with just one job title:

```
chairman of the board   TITLE   MISC    1
```

I ran on this text:

```
Chairman of the Board Bienaime Jean-Jacques
```

And I used this command:

```
java -Xmx8g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,regexner -file sample-sentence.txt -outputFormat text -regexner.mapping job_title.rules -regexner.ignorecase
```

I get "Chairman of the Board" as a "TITLE" and I get "Bienaime Jean-Jacques" as a PERSON.

This was all done with Stanford CoreNLP 3.7.0.

Also just for your information Stanford CoreNLP 3.7.0 comes with a large list of job titles.  You can detect job titles using the `regexner` annotator.  By default this annotator will use our list of job titles.  Though I admit "chairman of the board" is not in the list.  I will add it for future versions!

The list of job titles is in the file `edu/stanford/nlp/models/kbp/regexner_caseless.tab` which is located in the english-kbp models jar.  Available here: http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/download.html

Comment: updated with some more examples with a csv format of columns sentence_text,tokens,lemmas,ner_tags

Comment: also , I am still curios to understand How to define a regular expression over tokens, so if a TITLE is followed by ORGANIZATION then replace the ORGANIZATION to a PERSON

eg: /Match TITLE ORG/ -> { replace to} -> / TITLE PERSON/